# Javascript Scroll Height Percentage Math

Tags: javascript, html, math, height

I have a simple JS module that calculates the percentage of the current scroll position.

```
var scrollPercent = (function() {
    "use strict";

    var module = {
        config: {

        },
        init: function() {
            return this.percent();
        },
        percent: function() {
            var windowHeight = this.getWindowHeight();
            var docHeight = this.getDocHeight();
            var scrollPosition = this.getScrollPosition();
            var result = ((scrollPosition + windowHeight) / docHeight) * 100;

            return Math.floor(result);
        },
        getScrollPosition: function() {
            return (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;               
        },
        getWindowHeight: function() {
            return window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight || 0;
        },
        getDocHeight: function() {
            return Math.max(
                document.body.scrollHeight || 0, 
                document.documentElement.scrollHeight || 0,
                document.body.offsetHeight || 0, 
                document.documentElement.offsetHeight || 0,
                document.body.clientHeight || 0, 
                document.documentElement.clientHeight || 0
            );                
        }
    };

    return module;
});

var scroller = new scrollPercent;

window.onscroll = function(event) {
    console.log(scroller.init());
};
```

This is working as expected, if the window height is 500px and the doc height is 1000px, then the initial scroll position is 50%. If you were to scroll to the bottom it would be 100%.

What I would like to do is have my initial value be 1% and when scrolling to the bottom it return 100% (like it is now).

The problem is that my initial value of 50% is based off the window height (half the page is showing). For some reason I can't figure out the necessary math to have it start at 1% and go to 100% when reaching the bottom.

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve with this, what's the reasoning behind wanting 1% instead of 0%?

Comment: @Nit thats not what the issue is. If you read the question the OP doesn't want the initial height to take into account the current position of the page. So for a doc height of 1000px and window height of 500px instead of the initial window % being 50 OP wants it to be 1%. Although I am sure the OP wouldn't care if it was 0% instead of 1%

Comment: @Nit - I thought 1% would just be a good offset for visual effects to take place on the page when scrolling. Though, I could probably achieve what I'm looking for if it started at 0%. Thanks

Comment: @adjit - you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a bunch of fiddling I came across your solution...

You have to take into consideration the current position of the document and the scroll bar. So if you want to get it between 0-100 you have to exclude the height of the window in your `docHeight`.

In your function I created a variable called `initDiff` and basically used this to calculate your value between 0-100.

This is how I set up your `init` function. Notice `docHeight`. Also, notice `initDiff` which calculates a difference that needs to be subtracted from your result. I don't use any scroll positioning because the `initDiff` is calculated for when the scroll-bar positioning is `0`

```
init: function() {
    var windowHeight = this.getWindowHeight();
    var docHeight = this.getDocHeight() - windowHeight;
    initDiff = (windowHeight / docHeight) * 100;
    console.log('Difference : ' + initDiff);

    return this.percent();
}
```

Below is your percent function that I changed up a bit. Again, `docHeight` takes into consideration the current height of the window. Your result, once you take out the `windowHeight` from `docHeight` your number generally ranged from something like 50-150, it all depends on the window height. What I do is "keep" that number, but I calculate that difference. So for that range, your `initDiff` will be `50`. If the range was 56-156 your `initDiff` will be `56`

```
percent: function() {
    var windowHeight = this.getWindowHeight();
    var docHeight = this.getDocHeight() - windowHeight;
    var scrollPosition = this.getScrollPosition();            
    var result = ((scrollPosition + windowHeight) / docHeight) * 100 - initDiff;

    console.log('Window Height : ' + windowHeight);
    console.log('Document Height : ' + docHeight);
    console.log('Scroll Position : ' + scrollPosition);

    return Math.floor(result);
}
```

### Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XNVNj/2/

Just look at your console. Should explain it all.

Comment: I had something going like this initially but I didn't take it far enough. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @Pathsofdesign not a problem. It helped a lot to organize the console output, so once I figured out the range had a consistent difference to 0 & 100 respectively I just had to figure out a way to calculate and subtract out that difference